# Concatenar dos filas MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datatables

tengo esta QUERY cuya intención es devolver el genero que tiene asignado una determinada novela (tengo 3 tablas "NOVELAS", "GENEROS" y "NOVELAS_GENEROS" )

```
SELECT novelas.id AS novel_id, genres.genre_name 
FROM genres, genres_novels, novelas 
WHERE genres_novels.novel_id = novelas.id 
AND genres.id = genres_novels.genre_id AND genres_novels.novel_id = 23
```

Que me devuelve el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que me devuelva el resultado en formato "Maduro, Artes marciales" tal cual en una sola fila separado por comas (,)

He encontrado la funcion GROUP_CONCAT pero no alcanzo a entender como debo utilizarla.

No estoy seguro si es posible correr un select dentro de un GROUP_CONCAT pero creo que es lo que necesito ya que mi objetivo final es que la QUERY encargada de devolver los datos completos de todas las novelas registradas tengan sus generos tambien informados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debería bastar con hacer lo siguiente:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(genres.genre_name SEPARATOR ',') AS Listado
```

Indicando como segundo argumento la *keyword* `SEPARATOR`para establecer que símbolo separará cada uno de los elementos de la lista.

Finalmente haces un `GROUP BY` por la columna `novel_id` al final de tu consulta.

Comment: SI, he tenido que agregar unas cuantas cositas por que trabaja con varias tablas lo que necesito pero en resumidas cuentas esta sintaxis funciona. Gracias :)